# Django foreign key name on select

Tags: python, django

I'm working with 2 models, each one in a different Django application:

**App products:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.FloatField()
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**App warehouses:**

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The problem is that in the admin site, when I want to create a product and I need to select a warehouse, I only see the following in the select list:

```
Warehouse object
Warehouse object
Warehouse object
```

What do I have to do to see the warehouse name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__unicode__` method is only used in Python 2. Since you are presumably using Python 3, you should define `__str__` instead.

Comment: Yes you beat me to the punch!

Comment: @P. Rodoreda.  Check as acepted answer.